# Using QGIS Map Swipe Tool?

Tags: qgis, swipe

I'm using the Map Swipe Tool in QGIS 3.6.2 on a Mac and a PC. I'm using the tool on two imported raster layers to compare changes in temperature. On the PC, it works just fine. On the Mac, I'm getting a lopsided image (see attached image). I don't know if this is Mac related or not, but does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or why this might be occurring?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the left half of the raster is enlarged and offset to the southeast.

Comment: Yes, that happened when the swipe tool was used. It doesn't look like that when the swipe tool is turned off.

Comment: I just found this bug reported on GitHub (https://github.com/lmotta/mapswipetool_plugin/issues/11) so it seems that it is a version/Mac issue that will hopefully get resolved in future updates.